# CSS position relative without relative width?

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

I'd like an element to have relative positioning. But I don't want its child element (with `position:absolute`) to have relative width to the parent.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/t2yJP/. I'd like the second `body>div` to have `position:relative`, but have its child's width maintain the same behavior.

Comment: Why the vote to close? If its not possible, just say so.

Comment: I think the vote to close came about because it is quite difficult to understand what you are asking - but personally I don't think it deserved the close vote. If you mean that you want the text to flow out of the absolutely positioned `div`, like in your second example, then you can use `whitespace: nowrap`.

Comment: That's sort of what I was looking for. I want the absolutely positioned div to expand to its natural width, rather than be constrained by its `position:relative` parent. In the second example, the text will still wrap, it just won't be the parent width.

Comment: The "natural width" of a div is 100% of available space - which in this case will be 100% of the positioned parents width. So unless you specify a width on the absolutely positioned div itself then you will have change the way you a structuring your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2yJP/2/).

But you should really rethink your strategy. In your fiddle, your second example only works because the parent div is not positioned and therefore, the `.abs` div is technically not in the parent.

Normally, child elements are inside their parents. That's what containers are for! So if you don't want the `.abs` div to be constrained by the red rectangle, don't put it inside the red rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width:inherit` to the `.abs` class.

Comment: I'd like it the other way around. The first box to behave like the second.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve a similar-looking effect as follows:

```html
<div class='abs pad'>
    Content content content
</div>
<div class='rel pad red'>
</div>
```

```css
.rel {
    position: relative;
}
.abs {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.pad {
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
}
.red {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```